# About affine varities definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a definition from a Algebraic geometry book. I want some clarification on the definition,.

> Definition: (affine varities)
>
> 1). We call $\mathbb{A}^n:=\mathbb{A}^n_K:=\{(a_1,...,a_n):a_i \in K \textbf{for} i=1,...,n\}$ the affine n-space over K.
>
> 2). For a subset $S \subset K[x_1,...,x_n]$ of polynomials we call $V(S):=\{x \in \mathbb{A}^n:f(x)=0 \textbf{for all} f \in S\} \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ the (affine) zero locus of S. Subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n$ of this form are called (affine) varities. If $S=\{f_1,...,f_k\}$ is a finite set, we will write $V(S)=V(\{f_1,...,f_k\})$ also as $V(f_1,...,f_k)$.

Question about the definition above: Want to check: is $V(S)=x$ a vector? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why downvote? I will revise it.

Comment: $V(S)$ is a *subset* of affine $n$-space. If you take $S=\{x(y+1)\}$ (working in affine $2$-space), then $V(S)$ is the union of the $y$-axis (i.e. $x=0$) and the $x$-axis shifted by $1$ (i.e. $y=-1$).

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld Very helpful! Thx!